# Any way to reverse engineer split ac inverter compressor speed?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Summer has come and I've got myself an oversized inverter Air Conditioner (1.5 ton for 120sqft room) as suggested by some YouTubers.

**Details:**

```
Outdoor temp day: 43C, 
Night: 30/35
Relative Humidity: Less than 15%
Ac model: LG-LS-H18VNXD
Capacity: 1.5 Ton
Type: Hot and Cold
```

- **Problem 1:**
  The AC overcools, especially at night, I wake up shivering to turn off ac. I always set the temp to 30°C. I don't think the thermostat is faulty because the AC display shows the actual temperature on de-humidify mode, which is always 4-7 degrees lower than set.
- **Problem 2:** **Frequent power cuts here** and I want to run the AC on my pure sine wave 850va *inverter*. I have noticed that when the AC compressor runs on **low mode**, it consumes around **240Watts @ 220v.** And I have tested running it on my inverter and it works flawlessly. **But this low mode is rare**, it only happened once. Normally, it sucks around 800watts. And I feel even low mode is enough to cool my room comfortably.

Now, all I want to do is control the speed of the inverter compressor manually.

***I have two ideas***

1. I *believe* that the temperature sensor works on resistance, so I want to connect my own resistor instead of the temp sensor (but I don't know how to do it safely, here I need your guidance).
2. I noticed that the indoor unit communicates with the outdoor unit via a 4th wire. This communication must be analog but I can't find the working behind it. If there's a way to alter the communication signal to show low temp, it could work without the hassle of tricking the thermostat itself.

But both the ideas are **just my theory**, I have never opened up any AC unit before. Are these viable ideas and if so, how do I accomplish them safely.

And if there are any other idea to control the compressor speed directly?

*Please suggest a DIY solution to achieve this* I'm not open to alternatives like:

- talk to a technician (here technicians can only install AC, they have no clue about anything really technical). I am a programmer so I can adapt to some technical stuff
- Reverse the cold air back to top of AC to trick the thermostat (no, i tried that, its not a good solution and doesn't always work)
- getting a cooler (no, because its also a winter/heating AC)
- getting smaller AC (No the seller wont accept return and I am not wealthy enough to buy a separate AC).

*EDIT:*

So i opened the indoor unit to checkout the thermistor, after a lot of searching through pcb, found the culprit to be the open hole through which refrigerant pipes go via double roof ( the installer morons didnt close it properly), now its working fine. But again, i would like to manually control the VFD to run the ac on 850va inverter perhaps ? the lowest speed when temp is reached consumes 300watts and is cool enough.

I guess the PCB might have a override, but I didnt find any service manual for the particular model (LG LS18VNXD). Right now I just want the service manual of the A.C

Comment: Start by sizing the unit correctly - there are sites that do that. An iversized unit by 10% is one thing - 50% is a different ball game.

Comment: But inverter acs are supposed to maintain temperature right?

Comment: `But this low mode is rare` ... what causes the low mode to activate?

Comment: no idea actually, sometimes it works sometimes don't (by achieving set temperature) Maybe its a thermostat calibration issue ? But if i can trick the thermostat somehow to show 18C, then I am sure this can activate the low mode

Comment: isn't the thermostat just a switch?

Comment: Can you give us a model number? Some models have options to limit compressor speed for energy saving (demand response) reasons, or to reduce exterior noise at night.

Comment: A brand and model would be helpful, most inverters can be programmed but several use proprietary cables and figuring out all of the settings will be quite involved the last one I worked on has over 120 settings , about 30 were size specific and the wrong setting can damage your compressor the cable was sent to me with the replacement compressor & program for warranty work and I had to return it or pay 150$  changing the settings will void any warranty and the energy efficiency may go from 24 to 18 that’s what they mentioned if the auto tune Was not preformed properly, sounded crazy to me.

Comment: I ran out of room , if the unit is one that we have to have training for to get certified you probably not get any help, some of those classes cost over 1k and if some was caught hacking or helping someone hack a system poof no more business for that brand as they will pull the certification. Some systems do use thermistors (a resistor that changes value with temp) for your #1 idea others use thermocouples, the programs in the controller are not annotated (but I have only worked on 2) the controllers are just like a fancy VFD , if you have programmed these like for motors you may have luck.

Comment: Since the thermometer "is always 4-7 degrees lower than set", set the thermostat 4-7 degrees _higher_ so it cools to the desired _actual_ temperature. Sounds a lot safer and simpler than hacking into a brand new AC unit an voiding any warranty that it may have.

Comment: You realize Youtubers are just like any other random 4chan jackasses on the internet, right?  Their opinion isn't *more valid* merely because they have a video cam... In fact, if they have links in their show notes, they are affiliate links and they're paid to promote the product.  At least here, we have a competent reputation system, so you can evaluate answerer's expertise and watch bad advice get shouted down... **so it's really disturbing that you spend on fools' advice, ask real experts to clean up the mess, *but then, chain them up* so they can't give correct answers...**-1

Comment: give us the model # so we can look at the service manual and hopefully find a schematic or at least a wiring diagram that will guide modification. I would offer that you can't replace a thermister with a normal resistor, or else it will simply always or never run.

Comment: the main problem with oversizing shouldn't be it getting too cold (the thermostat regulates that), the problem should be too-frequent cycling, which you don't complain about. Keep a fan blowing on the thermostat to reduce the diff between the temp it sees and the temp your bed sees.

Comment: Model: LG LSH18VNXD. So i opened the indoor unit to checkout the thermistor, after a lot of searching through pcb, found the culprit to be the open hole through which refrigerant pipes go via double roof ( the installer morons didnt close it properly), which was directly near the thermistor, now its working fine. But again, i would like to manually control the VFD to run the ac on 850va inverter perhaps ? the lowest speed when temp is reached consumes 300watts and is cool enough.

Comment: @Subrata edit your question to include the model number.